# Git no inicia clonación

Tags: git, github

tengo un repositorio que quise clonar en otra pc con 'git clone ', pero solo me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se queda así y no muestra ningún error, ni nada. Lo único que me crea es la carpeta y su archivo '.git' con 25kb de peso. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Gracias :'v

Comment: Intenta utilizar otro terminal, me paso lo mismo la semana pasada con Git Bash

Comment: Sí era eso, muchas gracias :)